# Does CUDA 5 support STL or THRUST inside the device code?

Tags: cuda, thrust

Its mentioned that CUDA 5 allows library calls from kernel
Does that mean CUDA 5 can use thrust or STL inside device code then ?

Comment: In a word, no it doesn't.

Comment: @talonmies then what feature did nVidia really added by specifying "Library Calls from Kernels" ?

Comment: CUDA 5 has a device code linker for the first time. It means you can have separate object files of `__device__` functions and link against them rather than having to declare them at compilation unit scope. It also adds the ability for kernels to call other kernels (but only on compute 3.5 Kepler devices).

Comment: @talonmies is there any alternative for me to use STL like code in device ?

Comment: If by "STL like", you mean templated generic functions instantiated at compile time or that style of metaprogramming, then yes. If you mean actual functions from the C++ std library or thrust, then today the answer is no.

Comment: @talonmies thanks a lot for taking time to answer me. it was really helpful

Comment: This should be made as an answer

Answer (score 1):

CUDA 5 has a device code linker for the first time. It means you can have separate object files of **device** functions and link against them rather than having to declare them at compilation unit scope. It also adds the ability for kernels to call other kernels (but only on compute 3.5 Kepler devices).

None of this means that C++ standard library templates or Thrust can be used inside kernel code.