# Assignment of arrays in C++ like Matlab?

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab, matrix, cuda

So in `MATLAB`, if I make a `N x N x N x N x 6` dimensional matrix, I can assign values to the matrix in groups of 6 as so:

```
myMatrix(1,1,1,1,:) = [69, 3, 864, 21, 95, 20];
```

Is there an analogous way to write into an `N x N x N x N x 6` dimensional matrix in C++ in groups of 6?

Also, is there an analogous way to set 6 elements equal to another 6 elements I.e myArray(N,N,N,8,:) = myArray(N,N,N,6,:)?

(No std::vector solutions please- need to keep the matrix in array form as the existing code was built for arrays using `c++/CUDA` and is extremely complex)

Comment: You may want to clarify why you cant use `stl` solutions.

Comment: Do you want this to work with whatever data types (arrays) you're using right now, or can you replace it with a different data type, as long as the matrix elements are stored in contiguous memory?

Comment: Arrays highly preferred as I am a noob coder and I am familiar with them

Comment: One way to do this without `stl` would be to use expression templates, see [Implementing Matlab's colon : operator in C++ expression templates class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339207/implementing-matlabs-colon-operator-in-c-expression-templates-class). You may wish to have a look at the [BlueBird library](http://www.orangeowlsolutions.com/bluebird) which implements expression templates with CUDA.

Comment: For those who are proposing using `stl`: `stl` is not supported in CUDA kernel code. See [Using std::vector in CUDA device code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375680/using-stdvector-in-cuda-device-code) and [Does CUDA 5 support STL or THRUST inside the device code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052295/does-cuda-5-support-stl-or-thrust-inside-the-device-code).

Comment: It's cool, Jack, the matrix Is initialized on the host side code not the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `#include <algorithm>`, you may use `std::copy`:

```
int myMatrix[N][N][N][N][6];
const int src[6] = {69, 3, 864, 21, 95, 20};

std::copy(std::begin(src), std::end(src), myMatrix[0][0][0][0]);
```

And so the equivalent of `myArray(N,N,N,8,:) = myArray(N,N,N,6,:)` would be:

```
std::copy(std::begin(myMatrix[N-1][N-1][N-1][5]),  // Source start
          std::end(myMatrix[N-1][N-1][N-1][5]),    // Source end
          std::begin(myMatrix[N-1][N-1][N-1][7])); // Dest start
```

Note that indexing in C/C++ start at `0` and not at `1`.

Comment: Brilliant. Sorry for the second question but how can I use this method to set 6 elements equal to another 6 elements I.e myArray(N,N,N,8,:) = myArray(N,N,N,6,:)

Comment: Edited to add a solution of your additional question.

Comment: Does src[6] need to be of type const int? Can i make it just int?

Comment: It may be non `const`.

Comment: I'm trying to reuse src multiple times like:

float src[6] = {5,6,7,2,4,9};
src = {6,6,6,6,6,6};

But i get errors "expected an expression, "expression must be a modifiable lvalue"

Comment: C-arrays are not assignable, you may use `std::array<int, 6>` instead.

Comment: One last thing, 

src[6] can be a float array, right?

Comment: `src` may be a `float` array, but if `myMatrix` is an `int` matrix, you will have a conversion `float` to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign just like in matlab:
Say you have a vector:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>>>> myVector;
```

Assuming it has been initialised correctly like this:

```
myVector(N, std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>(N, std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>(N, std::vector<std::vector<int>(N, std::vector<int>(6, 0)))));
```

Gross. Try and do it differently or use push_back so it makes sense.

But, however you do it, you can then assign the lowest level vector like this:

```
std::vector<int> yourTempVector(6, someNumber);
myVector[1][1][1][1] = yourTempVector;
```

Comment: I can't use std::vectors in my program as I am actually using CUDA/C++ which forbids these constructs :(

Comment: @Jordan `Cuda` cant use `stl` types? Do you have to use arrays?

Comment: I don't know what stl is but I would really prefer to use arrays as it would mean minimal restructuring of an already highly complex program.

Comment: `stl` types are the standard c++ library types like `vector` and `map` and are basically what makes c++ good. You can use the `CUDA` specific types as shown here: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/#axzz35ip8zUwF

Comment: Thank you Ben, i'll keep that as a plan B.

Comment: Woah wait a sec, in your code example above (last part), does myVector need to be declared as an std::vector? or is it a multidimesional array?

Comment: In my code it is a std::vector which allows assignment like that. You can do this with arrays but it is more complex because you have to make sure the memory is managed correctly.

Comment: Note: indexing starts at `1` in matLab, so the equivalent should be `myVector[0][0][0][0] = yourTempVector;`.